# How to show percentage in the flutter web initialisation page?

Tags: html, css, flutter, flutter-engine

Currently I am showing a loader when the flutter web is getting initialised.

**Index:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->

  <base href="/">
  <!-- <base href="/interpreter/"> -->
  <!-- <base href="http://localhost/tolken/"> -->

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="Tolk2Go Tasker Web.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="tolk2go_tasker">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./loader.css">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
  <!-- <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://localhost/tolken/icons/Icon-192.png"> -->

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
  <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost/tolken/favicon.png"/> -->

  <title>Tolk2Go Tolken</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <!-- <link rel="manifest" href="http://localhost/tolken/manifest.json"> -->
   
  <script>
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (searchParams.has('renderer')) {
      window.flutterWebRenderer = searchParams.get('renderer');
      console.log(searchParams.get('renderer') + ' renderer requested in the URL');
    }
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
  <!-- <script src="http://localhost/tolken/flutter.js" defer></script> -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-analytics.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</body>
</html>
```

Loader:

```
.loader {
  border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 8px solid rgb(255, 132, 0);
  border-bottom: 8px solid rgb(255, 132, 0);
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 45%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Now I want to show the percentage of how much the app got initialized. How do I do that? If we won't be able to get the progress rate of initialization means, How should I show a progress percentage base on duration?